# Makefile NASM error: more than one input file specified

Tags: linux, assembly, makefile, nasm, ld

So, I have a makefile for some assembly code I'm working on and when I try to build my code I get the following output:

```
Makefile:32: warning: overriding commands for target `obj'
Makefile:29: warning: ignoring old commands for target `obj'
nasm -f elf64 -g -F stabs main.asm -l spacelander   .lst
nasm: error: more than one input file specified
type `nasm -h' for help
make: *** [obj] Error 1
```

Yet, when I Google for this it seems to be due to linker issues from LD rather than NASM itself (only NASM outputs in the error rather than LD), and I have only one source file which prints a simple text output as a test. In [this](http://forum.nasm.us/index.php?topic=1323.0) example, the OP was able to execute his code; mine won't even build.

AFAIK, my source file is perfectly fine, because before I altered it the code built and ran fine without any issues. I changed it though for the purposes of copying any `.o` files to an `obj/` directory, and the target to a `bin/` directory.

What could be the cause of this issue? I'm almost positive it has nothing to do with the code and is due to the Makefile itself.

For the sake of completeness, I'll paste both my Makefile and assembly source.

---

**Source**

```
bits 32

section [.bss]

section [.data]

; Store three lines in the same string. 
; This is just for test purposes.

Title: db "------SPACE LANDER-----", 10, \  
          "------SPACE LANDER-----", 10, \
          "------SPACE LANDER-----", 10 

Len: equ $-Title

section [.text]

    global _start

_start:

    mov     eax, 4     ; Syswrite
    mov     ebx, 1     ; To stdout
    mov     ecx, Title ; ecx stores title to print
    mov edx, Len   ; store offset of len in edx

    int     0x80       ; call kernel, do print

exit: 

    mov     eax, 1    ; exit
    mov ebx, 0    ; return 0
    int     0x80      ; call kernel, exit safely (hopefully)
```

**Makefile**

```
ASM  := nasm
ARGS := -f
FMT  := elf64
OPT  := -g -F stabs

SRC    := main.asm

#SRC_EXT := asm
#^unused due to suspected error causing. 

OBJDIR := obj 
TARGETDIR := bin

OBJ    := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(patsubst %.asm, %.o, $(wildcard *.asm)))
TARGET := spacelander   

.PHONY: all clean

all: $(OBJDIR) $(TARGET)

$(OBJDIR): 
    mkdir $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SRC)
    $(ASM) $(ARGS) $(FMT) $(OPT) $(SRC) -l $(TARGET).lst

$(TARGET): $(OBJ)
    ld -o $(TARGET) $(OBJ)

clean:
    @rm -f $(TARGET) $(wildcard *.o)
    @rm -rf $(OBJDIR)
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably due to the extra spaces in this command:

```
nasm -f elf64 -g -F stabs main.asm -l spacelander   .lst
```

Because you have extra spaces at the end of `$(TARGET)`, because you have extra spaces at the end of this line:

```
TARGET := spacelander
```

Try removing those extra spaces.

Comment: There is also an extra space at the end of `OBJDIR := obj `, which is causing the warning messages and will mess up the rest of the build even if the `nasm` command succeeds.